# Deleting a previous question as it does not add any value to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

This question [Dynamic selection of number of clusters in clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54359332/10953776) was asked by me with little knowledge in clustering in machine learning and does not add any value to this site. SO doesn't let me delete it, saying others have invested there time in answering the question (valid point), but the answers also don't add any value because they are answers to the original question and as already mentioned above the question is quite bad.

Can a mod step in and close it?

Comment: You can already vote to close your own question, e.g. as a duplicate. If you know a duplicate target, you should be able to click the “close” link beneath your question.

Comment: If you want your question closed and deleted you should be asking for upvotes. Then meta will help you obliterate your question. You want to _delete it_? Now meta will make sure it's remains there for ever and ever. (Just kidding, of course).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Already did that, It needs 4 votes